# What is the definition of a habitable home environment in the care and support eligibility criteria regulations 2015?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, definition

Article 2 paragraph 2(f) of the Care and Support (Eligibility Criteria) Regulations 2015 specifies the outcome of maintaining a habitable home environment. What is the definition of ‘habitable’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There is plenty of [case law](https://anthonygold.co.uk/latest/blog/how-bad-do-conditions-have-to-be-to-make-a-property-unfit-for-human-habitation/)

> Rendlesham Estates plc and others v Barr Ltd – [2015] 1 WLR 3663 summerised the recent caselaw on fitness for habitation and concluded that:
>
> The specific facts in each case should be considered.
> The property should be considered as a whole rather than defect by defect. So many more minor defects may have a cumulative effect.
>
> For a dwelling to be fit for habitation … it must …
>
> (a) be capable of occupation for a reasonable time without risk to the health or safety of the occupants: where a dwelling is or is part of a newly constructed building, what is a reasonable time will be a question of fact…; and
>
> (b) be capable of occupation for a reasonable time without undue inconvenience or discomfort to the occupants.
>
> The issues in this case causing properties to be unfit for habitation included damp, condensation mould, leaks and “a lift that …. broke down with monotonous regularity”.

Comment: To be fair I think this is in a fitness for human habitation act context rather than one of the regulation in question, but it seems possibly applicable.

Comment: @Seekinganswers habitable means habitable